# how can resolve dodgy:unchecked/unconfirmed cast in sonar?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, sonarqube, findbugs

iam getting the exception through sonar in this following code.How can I resolve this.Suggest me.

```
    @Override 
     public boolean validate(BaseInfo infoObject) { 
     boolean isValid = true; 
     AckTransferPaymentInfo ackTransferPaymentInfo = (AckTransferPaymentInfo) infoObject;
```

Dodgy - Unchecked/unconfirmed cast
Unchecked/unconfirmed cast from com.vocalink.acsw.common.validation.info.BaseInfo to com.vocalink.acsw.common.validation.info.AckTransferPaymentInfo in com.vocalink.acsw.validation.rule.T170Rule.validate(BaseInfo)

```
AckTransferPaymentElement payment = ackTransferPaymentInfo.getTransferPayment();  
if(CreditDebitIndicator.CRDT.equals(ackTransferPaymentInfo.getCreditDebitIndicator()) 
&& ackTransferPaymentInfo.getOriginalPaymentAccount().getAccountName() != null
```

Comment: Can you please post the declaration of classes : BaseInfo and AckTransferPaymentInfo

Comment: public interface BaseInfo,public interface AckTransferPaymentInfo extends BaseInfo

Answer (score 7):

You can check that the type of infoObject is correct and handle it appropriately when it's not:

```
if (!(infoObject instanceof AckTransferPaymentInfo)) {
    throw new AssertionError("Unexpected type: " + infoObject);
}
AckTransferPaymentInfo ackTransferPaymentInfo = (AckTransferPaymentInfo) infoObject;
```

You should verify this does what you want when infoObject is null.

Comment: even after this check, FindBugs seems to be reporting the error on this line# 4 in your code snippet