# findbugs Unchecked/unconfirmed cast from Throwable

Tags: java, exception, findbugs

I have some custom exception that should be retrieved from thrown InvocationTargetException, I do it in following way:

```
    try {
        ...
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException 
| NoSuchMethodException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
        if (e.getCause() instanceof CustomException) {
        throw (CustomException) e.getCause();
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
```

But findbugs complains me:

**Unchecked/unconfirmed cast from Throwable**

I found a silimar question ([how can resolve dodgy:unchecked/unconfirmed cast in sonar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067510/how-can-resolve-dodgyunchecked-unconfirmed-cast-in-sonar)), but it didn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that if you assign the cause to a local variable first, FindBugs will be able to figure things out correctly:

```
try {
    /* ... */
} catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException 
        | NoSuchMethodException | NoSuchFieldException e) {

    Throwable cause = e.getCause();

    if (cause instanceof CustomException) {
        throw (CustomException) cause;
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Comment: This works because FindBugs can't know that `getCause()` won't return different values on subsequent calls. The local variable fixes the value in place.